# return students; It's not work for me : (

Tags: java

I have to loop `nameFirst` , but i don't even know how to use return

```
public List<String> b(final List<Student> students) {
    String result = "";

    for(Student student : students){
       result +=student.nameFirst;
    }

    return students;
}
```

Problem solved
, thanks everyone It's work :))

```
public List<String> b(final List<Student> students) {
   List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Student student : students){
       result.add(student.nameFirst);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I mean, you're not doing anything with `result`.

Answer (score 2):

make your result as List and return it:

```
public List<String> b(final List<Student> students) {
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(students.size());

  for(Student student : students)
    result.add(student.nameFirst);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This method is supposed to return `List<String>`, yet this method returns just `Student` and it still does nothing with `result`.